# Screen sending is not working with GoogleAnalytics iOS SDK 3.11

Tags: ios, google-analytics-sdk

I am trying to send a screen to Google Analytics using its SDK (3.11) on iOS, but nothing is happening on the GA console, even after 24h.

I doubled checked the identifier which look like this UA-xxxxxxx-x.

Here is the code I use to setup the SDK :

- in my AppDelegate

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
  {
    [GAI sharedInstance].optOut = YES;
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 1;
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    [[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId: self.config.googleAnalyticsTrackingId];
    return YES;
  }
  ```
- in my ViewController, which inherits from GAITrackedViewController

  ```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.screenName = @"MyControllerScreen";
  }
  ```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have opted out of analytics data tracking..

```
[GAI sharedInstance].optOut = YES;
```

Comment for `optOut` property clearly states..

> When this is true, no tracking information will be gathered; tracking
>   calls  will effectively become no-ops.

So either set it to false `optOut = NO`, or just comment out that line and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually don't know why I have put it to YES, but by rereading the documentation, you are right, this line doesn't make any sense. I deleted it and it is now working like a charm.